# How does optical media converter provide administration web interface

Tags: networking, fiber, optical-media

I've been recently playing with the web administration of an optical media converter (Huawei HG8010) I have from my ISP and I wondered how does the web administration work.

By that I mean how does the device differentiate between LAN port traffic that should be forwarded to the optical WAN port and the traffic which tries to access the web administration? My guess is that it checks if the packets are addressed to the IP set in the administration (by default 192.168.100.1) in which case it responds but in the opposite case it just forwards the packets and acts as if it wasn't even there.

Is my assumption correct or is there something more going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's close, but your descriotion is more like how a *router* would work.

Optical media converters are layer-2 bridges (just like Ethernet managed switches or Wi-Fi access points), and the differentiation is done based on the destination **MAC address.** Very simplified, a bridge practically works like this:

1. Broadcast frames which contain an ARP or ICMPv6-ND query for the device's IP address are answered (but also forwarded to other bridge ports).
2. Frames having the bridge's MAC address as the 'destination' are passed up to the device's IP layer – and *then* either consumed or discarded based on IP address. (But not forwarded: only a router would forward at this step.)
3. All other frames are forwarded to other bridge ports, with no change to IP or MAC headers.

Notice that the logic in steps 1–2 is practically the same as in regular devices (like computers or routers). The only difference is what happens in step 3.

---

(And yes, just as is common with "wireless routers", some models of GPON media converters are all-in-one CPE devices and have the ability to be switched to router mode.)

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation. I didn't realize that the converter is just a bridge. So if the device was just a pure media converter without any option of configuration, only step 3 would be executed, right? And one more thing, in step 1 you wrote that the device would answer ARP for its own IP but also forward it. It seems to me that the forward shouldn't be needed as there shouldn't be any device with the same IP on the other side of the bridge and if there would be, that would mean a collision.

Comment: If the frame is broadcast then _it is broadcast_. It would mean a collision, yes, but it's **not the bridge's job** to prevent such things, whether they're accidental or even deliberate. (More so because it can't prevent collisions on the same side, anyway.)